# How to compile OpenGl and GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl

I Am on a Mac and I tried to compile OpenGL and GLUT but it does not work, why ?
Here is the command line that try to build (I use netbeans but this is the command line output window):

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries -lGL -lGLU
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glutInitWindowPosition", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <glut.h>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    glutInitWindowPosition(1,1);
    return 0;  
}
```

Here is my netbeans config
[image]
[image]

For information, there is no lib directory in /System/Library/Framework/GLUT.framework...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try with these `-framework GLUT -framework OpenGL`

and possibly:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it with Xcode importing the 2 frameworks (because I can't in netbeans). The compilation and linking is successful, but no windows was displayed

Comment: @johnathanMhehdi: Well, why should there? Your code doesn't create any windows.